# Chrome extension rejected saying "Your Product violates the Privacy Policy & Secure Transmission section of the policy"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I submitted a chrome extension which is rejected saying

```
Your Product violates the Privacy Policy & Secure Transmission section of the policy, which requires that:


If your Product handles personal or sensitive user data (including personally identifiable information, financial and payment information, health information, authentication information, website content and resources, form data, web browsing activity, user-provided content and personal communications), then your Product must:

 > Post a privacy policy, and

 > Handle the user data securely, including transmitting it via modern cryptography.
```

The following is the `manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "short_name": "__MSG_appShortName__",
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "version_name": "0.0.1 beta",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "default_locale": "en",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon-19.png",
      "38": "images/icon-38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "__MSG_browserActionTitle__"
  },
  "options_page": "pages/options.html",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "css": ["styles/contentscript.css"],
      "js": ["scripts/contentscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "downloads", "storage", "tabs", "<all_urls>"],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["images/*"]
}
```

The extension collects the URLs of the images on the active tab and when user chooses, will download those images from background, and I do not collect any data (The extension is open-source at [gallery-master](https://github.com/saisandeepvaddi/gallery-master) to verify).

Could someone please let me know

1. Any pointers on what to include in privacy policy as I do not know what kind of language or legal wording to use. Also, I do not collect any of the user data.
2. Is it not allowed to get image if image URL is not `https`.  (based on their second point which says handle user data securely. I am not sure if images on the webpage a user visits is part of user data which is directly processed in the user browser and not going anywhere to external links).

Any other things you think are reasons to for rejection and what am I supposed to change before submitting again?

Comment: Without seeing the full code I can only guess they don't understand themselves what they're writing (these particular reviewers weren't programmers) or it's an automated message. Try replying and asking for an exact quote of the offending code.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, I've mailed them askings specifics. They approved now without any changes. Thank you :)

Comment: I too have been getting this message without cause. The identified lines, same as OP, are definitely not at fault with this submission. I've written a reply and will see if I'm as lucky as @SaiSandeepVaddi